# Android GCM Work on ICS but not on gingerbread

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-cloud-messaging, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a problem with the GCM service.

My app correctly work on android >= 4.0 device but not (e.g) on gingerbread.

I think that the problem it's the manifest but seem right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 

       <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
              <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


            <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

          <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="MapTest" />
  </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

              <service android:name="com.example.maptest.GCMIntentService" android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

And my class

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
        Log.d(TAG,"CREATO IL Servizio");
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
        /*TODO*/
        MainActivity.regId=registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

}
```

In the LogCat nothing it's displayed.

Can someone help me ?
Thank's!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is `com.example.maptest` your package name, it should be the one that you declare in your manifest file in

```
<category android:name="MapTest" />
```

to be something like this

```
<category android:name="com.example.maptest" />
```

Comment: thank's! Now i think that the service work but answer me with the error "missing account" in the AVD. Why? I'm using AVD machine with Google Apis :-(

Comment: On earlier Android versions you need to be logged in with an account on the phone to get the push messaging to work: "it must have at least one logged in Google account if the device is running a version lower than Android 4.0.4" - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#arch

Comment: In the Beta version which is C2DM you have to have an gmail account to authenticate yourself to the service which used to push message and also you have to have google play app installed in either the actual device or the emulator.